# Can't get dynamic python ModelChoiceField to work

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to python and trying to understand how to get a dynamic ModelChoiceField to work.  It works fine when I select an object with all but I'm trying to get the dropdown to reflect a user's attribute.  Here is my code:

Forms.py

```
class ViewByMake(forms.Form):
    dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Make.objects.none())

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(ViewByMake, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = Make.objects.filter(user=user)
    self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = qs
    self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
    self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
```

Views.py

```
def view_bymake(request):
form = ViewByMake(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        make = form.cleaned_data['dropdown']   
        return HttpResponseRedirect(make.get_absolute_url1())
return render(request,'make/view_make.html',{'form':form})
```

This code works fine if I remove all user= references but then only returns the full make objects list which is not what I want.  I found a very similar question on StackOverflow, but when I duplicated the code identically, it still doesn't work and it is giving me the following error:

**init**() got multiple values for argument 'user'

I searched the end of the internet on this topic.  I'm open to other ideas if I'm approaching this poorly.  I'm trying to basically get a filtered list based on criteria associated with a user's profile.  I definitely need the drop down field to be specific to a user based on a profile setting.  Thanks for your help in advance.  I'm running django 1.11.2 and Python 3.6.1.

This is the updated model which need to include the user attribute which I didn't realize that I had to specify:

```
  class Make(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
       user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you remove the user argument in the init defionition and try again? I think you are having user twice in the call: first it will get user=request.Post and then  user=request.user

Comment: @NeErAj KuMaR I tried your suggestion and I received the following error:Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field.

Comment: @ger.s.brett I tried that before posting but tried again and got Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field.

Comment: but this is a different issue: does your model Make have a field "user"? Ca you post the model?

Comment: @ger.s.brett You are correct.  I was missing the user on the Make field.  I have since added it and it is now working.  Thanks for contributing.  For others sake I have posted by models code.  However, now that I have it working, I'm trying to understand if this function is limited to users, or can you also leverage other attributes on the user profile as well?  I just started playing with the syntax and haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: I do not understand rstwhat you want to achive?

Comment: @ger.s.brett I was trying to understand if you could set user=user to other attributes.  I played around a bit and found that you can set the user=user to other values, depending on what you are trying to achieve.  Essentially I was trying to figure out how to filter based on user profile.  I ultimately was able to find the appropriate filters for userprofile.  Thanks for contributing to my questions.  I appreciate the feeback and the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my original question, how do I get user=user to work consists of making sure that your form, view, and model all reference user.  I originally had the user reference in the view and the form correct, but I neglected to make sure user= was specified on the model I was referencing.  I thought it was built in, but turns out you have to specifically reference it on your model.  I'm new at this so it was a learning experience.  On to the next challenge!

Answer (score 0):

Try with request, send request from form and get request in **init** method of form

views.py

```
def view_bymake(request):
    form = ViewByMake(request.POST or None, request=request)
```

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(ViewByMake, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = Make.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = qs
    self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
    self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''
```